# Google Coder and Debian

Tags: raspbian-jessie

I discovered this last night http://googlecreativelab.github.io/coder/ I was curious if I installed this on a pi, would i still be able to use terminal? The reason I ask is because I wanted to make a UI for output display in html5 and bootstrap. Is this possible or does google coder get rid of any possibility to use terminal?

Comment: You can access a terminal on _any computer_ _anywhere_ , I just don't know how complicated it would be. Chances are, if you connect a monitor, keyboard, and mouse to the rpi, you be able to login and use the terminal right away. Also, try ssh-ing into it... just type `ssh coder.local` into a terminal on a different computer(although it's likely google coder doesn't have an ssh server active, so this most likely won't work).

Comment: That's not true.  You can't use the terminal on OSMC installs on the Raspberry PI for example so this is very much a valid question.

Comment: Terminal access is not easily available on (Google's) Android, either, which runs on the pi, so this is a bit presumptuous.  As it turns out it is a correct presumption though, this is just Raspbian packaged with the Coder app and some related tweaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Their [github page](https://github.com/googlecreativelab/coder/) makes it clear this is a node.js based application included in a (slightly) customized Raspbian distribution.  I would guess based on skimming through what's there that it is not a fully independent distro but rather one where changes have simply been made to the initial image, and thereafter it will just be normal Raspbian.

So no, you will not have to give up something as fundamental as terminal access.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I would have just downloaded it and tried myself, but I am limited to a single pi and really didn't want to restart everything I did if it wouldn't have worked.